# jQuery - Hide a particular div until another is clicked and hide that div again when div is hovered off

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is what I am trying to do.  I have a button (#facebook-button) that when clicked will show the contents of a div (#facebook).  Now I want it so when the mouse is not on top (hover) of the div #facebook that it then hides the div #facebook.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('#facebook').hide();

    jQuery('#facebook-button').click(function() {
    jQuery('#facebook').show();
    });

});

</script>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Even can you add your html markup.

Comment: Add a mouseout handler.

Comment: the answers below cover what you're basically saying, but that make the assumption that you want on mouse exit to do this action. Is that the correct behavior?? The way you're saying this is "When button clicked show. When mouse is not in (At all) hide". This wording is different from what they are showing

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles Better use mouseleave in this case.

Comment: @CayceK When the mouse is not in (at all) hide would result in hiding #facebook instantly again, just after the user had clicked the button, becuase #facebook-button is outside #facebook

Comment: @StefanWittwer you are correct. Which is why I'm asking the user to clarify. If the user does not have it set up the way you assume then again, there is different functionality. The user has not provided any information on the actual structure of the HTML. Like I said. The below answers cover the basic question, but is it exactly what the user is asking?

Comment: @CayceK Due to the user accepting my answer I assume that's what he was asking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's on mouseleave event, that event is fired when the mouse leaves the area.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#facebook').hide().on('mouseleave', function() {
            jQuery('#facebook').hide();
        });

        jQuery('#facebook-button').click(function() {
            jQuery('#facebook').show();
        });

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#facebook').hide();

    jQuery('#facebook-button').click(function() {
        jQuery('#facebook').show();
        $('#facebook').on('mouseenter', function() {
           // do something or remove that part to just leave mouseleave
        }).on('mouseleave', function(){
              $('#facebook').hide();
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

Basically after showing the div, we will just spot when his mouse is leaving the #facebook div to hide it.
You could also optimize the code and put $('#facebook') in a variable considering the amount of time you re use it. Saves you calling jquery more times than actually needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try some thing like this.
CSS

```
div { display: none; }
```

HTML

```
<a id="hover" href="#">Show</a>
<div id="div">Contents</div>
```

JS

```
$('#hover')
   .mouseleave(function() {
      $('#div').hide();
   })
   .click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $('#div').show();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/j4xxq03d/).

```
$('.fbContent').hide();
$('button').hover(
    function() {
        $('.fbContent').show();
    },
    function() {
        $('.fbContent').hide();
    }
)
```